# Android - title_section - change color

Tags: android, colors

I am testing a litte App-Development with the Android SDK and I have a question:

Is it possible to change the color of the Background and/or the Text at one section in the Menu?

I want to change the color at the marked area in the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZsvG.png

Thanks a lot!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear what exaclty you want to change, but these resources will give you the means to change any aspect of your view's color.

You can change colors within your xml:

With xml within the mark up or using styles and themes.

[Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

[Style Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html)

```
<TextView
    android:background="@drawable/myDrawable"
  or
    android:background="#F0F0F0"
```

Or programmatically:

```
// if you're interested in a listview.

ListView lv  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my Id In My Xml);

ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); // source of your list.

final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);


lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {
         lv.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

With any element.Same prinicples work for other elements.

Hope this helps.